# how to calculate in excel multiple taxes on amount of money?

Tags: excel

I want to make a function in excel program to calculate multiple taxes.

x=main salary = 30000 as an example.
then >>
I divide the x into 10000s 
the first 10000 in x has no tax, 
the second 10000 in x has 10% as tax,
more than that has 15% as tax

I need 
main salary - taxes = real salary.

Comment: What have you tried? How is your data stored? It seems like a straightforward math statement, perhaps with `IF()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: i entered 0 in A1 and 10%  in B1 and 15% in C1
i also put the main salary in A5 as you mentioned
i copied your function but it didn't work

Comment: Do you want the result of the Tax or just the Real Salary?

Comment: Both 
once i have an amount of tax i'll minus it with main salary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Formula for the Tax is:
`=IF(A1-10000>0,IF(A1-20000>0,(A1-20000)*15%+(10000*10%),(A1-10000)*10%),0)`

A1 the initial salary
In case the salary is <= 10000 no Tax it returns 0
If will test

- In case A1-20000 >0 True will apply 15% on A1-20000 + 10000*10%
- In case A1-20000 <=0 10% will be applied to A1-10000

The result will be the Total Taxes